# MSVAD Virtual Audio Sample Driver "Inf2Cat Signability test failed" (Windows WDK 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, wdk, inf, driver-signing

So I'm working on a virtual audio driver for Windows.

**HOST MACHINE:** Windows 8.1 w/Windows Driver Kit 8.1
**TEST/TARGET MACHINE:** Windows 8.1 connected via Network (Ethernet/Wi-Fi).
**IDE:** Visual Studio 2013 Express
**PROJECT:** MSVAD (Virtual Audio Driver)

Deployment configuration is for Win7x64.

For reference please see this sample tutorial: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/virtual-audio-device-3d4e6150#content

### PROBLEM:

See tutorial link above. Under "Build Sample" after "5. Locate the built driver package" the tutorial shows a list of files you should have in the directory.
For me I have those files under `C:\MSVAD\C++\x64\Win7Debug\package`.
They are all there except `msvad.inf` and `msvad.cat`.
However `msvad.inf` does show up under `C:\MSVAD\C++`.

When I build the project I get these two errors:

```
Error : Driver Deployment Task Failed: Driver Preparation (x64) (possible reboot) C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\build\x64\ImportAfter\DriverDeployment.targets 69 9 package (Package\package)
Error : Driver Deployment Task Failed: Driver Install (x64) (possible reboot) C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\build\x64\ImportAfter\DriverDeployment.targets 69 9 package (Package\package)
```

But then I was able to get the `msvad.inf` file to the correct directory by going into project settings (in Solution viewer) by adding the msvad.inf to include in the \package directory (still not the msvad.cat file though), but when I build the project this error showed up:

```
Inf2Cat Tool Output: ................................ Signability test failed.
Errors: 22.9.7: DriverVer set to incorrect date (must be postdated to 4/21/2009 for newest OS) in \msvad.inf
Warnings: None
```

I have been trying hard to figure this out. I'm pretty sure that this has to do with the `msvad.cat` file. I tried using `Inf2Cat.exe` under the `\bin` of the WDK directory but it won't open for me. When I try opening it from CMD in Admin Mode it says access is restricted or something. Even if I got it to open I'm not 100% sure what to do. I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I found a tutorial that helped solve the problem. Just a step-by-step on what to do.

See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919238(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The error message: `DriverVer set to incorrect date (must be postdated to 4/21/2009 for newest OS` - is pretty self-descriptive. There shall be a `DriverVer` parameter in the `[Version]` INF section specifying a date. Naturally, dates before 2009 don't make sense for Win7+.

If your driver is older, it was probably designed for XP x64. Then you can pass the check with [`/os:XP_X64`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919238(v=ws.10).aspx) argument to `inf2cat`.

Answer (score 0):

Plz set the below configuration:

Solutions is project->properties->ConfigurationProperties->inf2Cat->General->UseLocalTime->Yes